# display blank select if model isn't associated with another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I'm wondering - i have two models,`Device has many Phones` and vice versa. in the form for Phone I've got a select for a Device. I can't allow blank values to be inserted into this select, but somehow i need to display no value if no Device is associated.I can't figure out how to use [javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/R9auG/)

```
= f.input :device_ids, include_blank: false, label: false, as: :select, collection: current_user.devices, input_html: {id: "phone_number_#{phone_number.id}_device_ids", disabled: (true if phone_number.multiring)}
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue - added inline javascript(haml)

```
 = f.input :device_ids, include_blank: false, label: false, as: :select, collection: current_user.devices, input_html: {id: "phone_number_#{phone_number.id}_device_ids", disabled: (true if phone_number.multiring)}
      - unless phone_number.devices.first
        :javascript
          $("#phone_number_#{phone_number.id}_device_ids").prop('selectedIndex', -1)
```